# Check for Array in Jagged Array

Tags: c#

I am trying to search an array in a jagged array.

The following code does not work. What is my mistake here?

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2 };

int[][] varray = new int[2][];

varray[0] = new int[] { 1, 2 };
varray[1] = new int[] { 3, 4 };

if (varray.Contains(array1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("varray contains array1");
}
```

Comment: Only option is to make a for loop or any kind of loop to check for all values.

Comment: Like this?        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                if (varray[i] == array1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("varray contains array1");
                }
            }

Comment: `== array1[i]` and don't use `< 2` use `< varray.length` and check for  `&& i < array1.length` in `if()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if (varray.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(array1)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("varray contains array1");
}
```

Your `array1` and `varray[0]` points to different locations in the memory therefore `varray[0] == array1` will return **false**.

So if you do this:

```
varray[0] = array1;
```

Then `Contains` will return **true**.This is the only way to get `true` from `Contains` (without implementing a custom comparer) because even if the two array contains same elements, they are pointing to different locations in the memory.Instead try to use `SequenceEqual`, it will return true if the two array contains *same elements* in the *same order*.

Comment: This is merely an example. I do not want to set the first array of the jagged array equal to the array i want to check.

Comment: @user3369658 Arrays are reference types.even if the both array contains same elements, they are pointing to different locations in the memory.So you can't use Contains in this case.Try `Any` and `SequenceEqual` as shown above

Answer (score 0):

The default equality comparer for arrays in C# will only find two arrays to be equal if they both have the same reference. If you replace your declaration of `varray[0]` with this:

```
varray[0] = array1;
```

You'll now find that the `contains` check returns true. Though there are a few ways to deal with this, one particularly clean one is to use the `contains` overload which allows you to specify a custom equality comparer. Then you would write

```
(varray.Contains(array1, new SequenceEqualityComparer()))
```

And your equality comparer class would be:

```
public class SequenceEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<int> x, IEnumerable<int> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<int> obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example how to do it not fancy like
Demo on this URL https://ideone.com/rsUxTn

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        int[] array1 = { 1, 2 };

        int[][] varray = new int[4][];

        varray[0] = new int[] { 1, 2 };
        varray[1] = new int[] { 3, 4 };
        varray[2] = new int[] { 3, 4, 1 };
        varray[3] = new int[] { 3, 4, 9, 10 };

        Console.WriteLine("varray.length = " + varray.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("varray[0].length = " + varray[0].Length);

        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < varray.Length; i++) { 
            Console.WriteLine(" i = " + i);
            for(int j = 0; j < varray[i].Length; j++) {
                if (j < array1.Length && varray[i][j] == array1[k++]) {                                                                      
                    Console.WriteLine(" j = " + j);
                    Console.WriteLine("varray contains array1"); 
                }
            }
            k = 0;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. It will find it twice because it matched both elements 1 by 1.. you could fix that to only print message if it matched it completely.